# Invalid signature detected: Check Secure Boot policy

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I had an old setup with Windows 11 and Ubuntu on my Gigabyte X370. I installed Windows with only one SSD in the system, then removed it, installed Ubuntu on another SSD and plugged them both in.

If I wanted to use either, I could select the SSD via BIOS.

It was working perfectly.

I have since moved both SSDs into a new Gigabyte Z790 motherboard.

The Windows 11 SSD boots fine, Secure Boot is enabled, etc.

But when I try to select the Ubuntu SSD I get the following error in the BIOS "Invalid signature detected: Check secure boot policy".

I tried enrolling .efi images from the BIOS in from the drive but they failed every time. I also tried disabling Secure Boot but it automatically enables itself when I restart the computer.

I am not sure what to do now, I don't want to reformat the SSD again by removing all my other drives as it will take really long for me to unscrew everything and I have data I want to keep.

I tried reinstalling the grub using the following method.

```
1. boot into a usb flashed ubuntu.

2. sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt # sda is my ubuntu ssd
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```

It fails here saying that there is no efi.

Comment: In a nutshell, you're in a predicament entirely created by yourself, due to a mix a worrying misunderstanding of UEFI, its requirements and boot process, and disregard for recommended practices.

Comment: where can i read up about it or could you give me some advice on what I can do ? I have no idea what secure boot is.

Comment: Secure Boot is required for Windows 11 so you'll have to keep it. It has nothing to do with the problem. The problem started with the incorrect installation method that in spite of that worked for the cumbersome "drive selection" in the old board, doesn't work in the new. By default multi-boot system correctly installed in UEFI mode should have only one ESP, that mean when installing Ubuntu after Windows you can and should use the ESP already there - NO disk removal, you want that drive to be present so the Ubuntu installer adds Grub to the ESP. Now you may try to use Boot Repair (...)

Comment: (...) and reinstall Grub.

Comment: so if I install it without removing the other drives right now, I will have to use the ubuntu boot manager to select which operating system I want? what happens if i remove the ubuntu drive one day? will my windows boot manager still work?

Comment: That's the more practical idea, indeed. And, as always when dual-booting with anything Windows 8 or newer, disable its "Fast Startup" feature *before* installing or re-installing, so there won't be issues reading the Windows partitions and the ESP. You may do a manual partitioning and re-use the existing partitions as long as you select the ESP on the first drive as such (efi partition) or you can just reinstall Grub properly - even if Ubuntu was incorrectly installed in Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode before it should be easy to install grub-efi (Linux has no requirement about GPT/MBR, unlike Windows)

Comment: so just to be sure, if i do it this way, if i were to select the windows ssd as the first device to boot in bios, it would let me just boot straight into windows as per normal. if i select the ubuntu ssd as the first device, it would go into grub and let me select either ubuntu or windows correct? i already tried reinstalling grub, i kept getting a missing efi error. maybe i am doing it wrong? is there a guide on how i can reinstall it ? i boot into a flash disk ubuntu then i ran the following commands which i will update my original question with.

Comment: No, you're still not getting it. UEFI DOESN'T boot "drives", it boots .efi entries. If correctly installed as recommended above it'll depend on the "OS Selection" (or equivalent) in the Boot menu, NOT the drive. All bootloaders are installed in the original ESP regardless of where the OSes system partitions reside. Yes, you can boot each one directly but you DON'T change the drive boot order, ONLY the OS (and of, course, when "Ubuntu" (GRUB) is selected you'll have an option to chainload Windows whereas with "Windows bootloader manager" selected it'll boot Windows directly).

Comment: Ok I understand finally. Last time when I installed ubuntu like 8 years ago i think it didnt work like that or maybe i got mixed up. Thanks!